# if $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty $. Real Analysis (Continous function)

Tags: real-analysis

If if $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and $f(x) \to 0$ as  $x \rightarrow \pm \infty $. How to prove that $f(x)$ is bounded ?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/252387/28900).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x) = 0$, then there exists $R>0$, such that
$$|f(x)|\leqslant 1,\qquad \mbox{ for } |x|\geqslant R.$$
Since $f$ is continuous, by compactness of $[-R,R]$ there exists $C>0$, such that
$$|f(x)|\leqslant C, \mbox{ for } x\in [-R,R].$$ 
We can conclude that
$$|f(x)|\leqslant \max\{ 1, C\},$$
for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.