# Show that f is bounded if f is continuous, finite and the limit exists.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that f is continuous on [0,+∞) and lim x→+∞ f(x) exists and finite.
Show that f is bounded on [0, +∞)

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252387/show-f-is-bounded-on-a-infty-if-continuous-there-and-lim-limits-x-to-i?rq=1

Comment: No, you show it. Or at least give us some indication about what problem you're having. This is not a site for you to dump your homework problems on and have the Internet magically solve them for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x) \rightarrow c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.  This means that $f(x)$ is within a given $\varepsilon > 0$ distance of $c$ for all $x$ sufficiently large.

Thus, there is an $N$ such that $f$ is bounded $[N, \infty)$.  You can now apply continuity to show that it is bounded on $[0, N]$ in a number of ways:

- Using the extreme value theorem, suggested by smcc below.
- Using the fact that the continuous image of a compact set is compact (which in $\mathbb{R}^n \implies$ bounded)
- Using the fact that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous.

Comment: How does showing continuity show that it is bounded?

Comment: Extreme value theorem